# FFMPEG is it faster to concat protocol or demux multiple h264 and aac mp4s?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to combine multiple mp4 videos encoded with h264 as the video codec and aac as the audio codec.

The mp4 videos have differing durations.

Is it faster to use the concat protocol or do a concat demux?

Answer (score 1):

Use the concat demuxer with `-c copy`. The concat protocol does not work with MP4 files.

Comment: I used now the concat protocol on h264 file and it works